# JS - проблема с селектором

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

С помощью плагина jQuery UI Dialog нужно сделать всплывающее окно.
Есть проблема с селектором.
Сейчас все выглядит так:

```js
$(function() {
  if (window.screen.availWidth <= 479) {
    $(".dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: window.screen.availWidth,
      title: "Запрос прайса",
      closeText: "",
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(".dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 400,
      title: "Запрос прайса",
      closeText: "",
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      }
    });

  }


  $(".opener").on("click", function() {
    $(".dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="left">
  <div class="dialog"></div>
</div>
<div id="center">
  <a class="opener">Open Dialog</a>
</div>
```

Все работает как надо.
Но сейчас надо сделать так:

```js
$(function() {
  if (window.screen.availWidth <= 479) {
    $("#center .dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: window.screen.availWidth,
      title: "Запрос прайса",
      closeText: "",
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("#center .dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 400,
      title: "Запрос прайса",
      closeText: "",
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      }
    });

  }


  $(".opener").on("click", function() {
    $("#center .dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="left">
  <div class="dialog"></div>
</div>
<div id="center">
  <div class="dialog"></div>
  <a class="opener">Open Dialog</a>
</div>
```

Но работает некорректно. Блок скрывается как нужно, но при нажатии на .opener ничего не происходит. Где ошибка?

---

Update: при правке кто-то внес ссылки на библиотеки. у меня другие:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

---

Update: Если бы я мог дать уникальный id этому элементу, вопроса бы не было.
Если ли возможность как-то обратиться к нему еще?

---

В итоге пришлось прописать перед функцией диалогового окна функцию добавления #id нужному элементу:

```js
  $( function() {
  $(".center > .dialog").each(function() {
   $(this).attr("id", "dialog-center"); 
  });
  })
```

И уже потом обращаться к нему по id. Если кто-то знает более изящное решение, буду благодарен.

Comment: `$( "#center" ).dialog( "open");` вот так попробуйте.

Comment: не работает, к сожалению

Comment: А в консоле браузера ошибки не наблюдается ?

Comment: Касающиеся этого - нет, вроде. Посмотрите test.afinalux.ru #column-left .dprice и .contbot .dprice

Comment: @DmitryUvarov `$("#center .dialog").dialog();` так нельзя обращаться к объекту, если вы вешаете на него dialog, в этом то и проблема, просто дайте уникальный `id` и тогда будет всё корректно работать, должно быть так: `$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );`

Comment: @RifmaMan Не могу дать уникальный id. Это модуль cms, который я могу вывести в той или иной позиции на странице и у него всегда один class(id)

Comment: @DmitryUvarov В ходе отладки я выяснил (точней у меня лишь этот вариант получился) что, вешать `.dialog` нужно на прямую, а не через родителя, лишь тогда он отрабатывает, к сожалению не знаю почему.

Comment: и напишитt тернарочку `const width = window.screen.availWidth <= 479 ? window.screen.availWidth : 400`

Answer (score -2):

Вам нужно на прямую обращаться к объекту, на который вешаете dialog, не знаю почему, но это работает только так, смотрите [пример от разработчика](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#entry-examples).

```js
$(function() {
  if (window.screen.availWidth <= 479) {
    $("#dialog_center").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: window.screen.availWidth,
      title: "Запрос прайса",
      closeText: "",
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("#dialog_center").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 400,
      title: "Запрос прайса",
      closeText: "",
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      }
    });
  }

  $(".opener").on("click", function() {
    $("#dialog_center").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="left">
  <div id="dialog_left"></div>
</div>
<div id="center">
  <div id="dialog_center"></div>
  <a class="opener">Open Dialog</a>
</div>
```